# Odoo - How to set field value from parent_id?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I am making a module that is adding additional field to partner form. As the value is the same for the partner companies it would have to be the same for all employees of the company.
[image]

Succeded to write the code to copy to child_usrs:
[image]

The problem is I cannot edit the field anymore...

My code:

```
class SpgMovField(models.Model):
_name = 'res.partner'
_inherit = 'res.partner'

spg_mov = fields.Char(string='MOV', compute='_compute_mov_from_parent', help='Minimum Order Value')
@api.one
@api.depends('parent_id', 'parent_id.spg_mov')
def _compute_mov_from_parent(self):
    if self.parent_id:

        self.spg_mov = self.parent_id.spg_mov

    elif type(self.id) is not models.NewId:
        query = """
        SELECT
            spg_mov
        FROM res_partner
        WHERE id=%s"""
        self.env.cr.execute(query, [self.id])
        result = self.env.cr.dictfetchone()

        self.spg_mov = result['spg_mov']



@api.one
def _inverse_persist_fields(self):
    query = """
    UPDATE res_partner
    SET
        spg_mov=%s
    WHERE id=%s"""

    params = [SpgMovField._optional(self.spg_mov)]
    self.env.cr.execute(query, params)
    self.env.invalidate_all()

@api.model
@api.onchange('parent_id')
def onchange_parent_id_new_mov(self):
    old_res = super(SpgMovField, self).onchange_parent_id(self.parent_id.id)
    _LOGGER.info(repr(old_res))
    if type(old_res) is dict and 'value' in old_res:
        for field, value in old_res.get('value').items():
            if hasattr(self, field):
                setattr(self, field, value)

    if self.parent_id:
        fields_to_copy = ['spg_mov']

        for key in fields_to_copy:
            self[key] = self.parent_id[key]

@staticmethod
def _optional(condition, value = None, defaultValue = None):
    if value is None:
        value = condition
    return value if condition != False else defaultValue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to use Odoo's commercial fields logic:

```py
class ResPartner(models.Model):
    _inherit = "res.partner"

    my_field1 = fields.Char()
    my_field2 = fields.Char()

    @api.model
    def _commercial_fields(self):
        """ Returns the list of fields that are managed by the commercial entity
        to which a partner belongs. These fields are meant to be hidden on
        partners that aren't `commercial entities` themselves, and will be
        delegated to the parent `commercial entity`. The list is meant to be
        extended by inheriting classes. """
        commercial_fields = super(ResPartner, self)._commercial_fields()
        new_commercial_fields = ['my_field1', 'my_field2']
        commercial_fields.extend(new_commercial_fields)
        return commercial_fields
```

Comment: Thanks - it is working perfectly fine. Regardless of the fact I have tried to reinvent the wheel where could be an issue? I see I forgot to call inverse def but it won't solve

Comment: Honestly i don't want to think about it ;-) You're using direct queries where i see the first problem, because you undermine the ORM layer with it. But just try thinks, without trying you will learn nearly nothing!